# Sticky Sidebar with JavaScript - Sticky only until specifed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to create a sticky sidebar. But the sticky sidebar should only be stick until the ending of the sidebar has reached a specifed element.

Here is the webpage I want to get worked with the sidebar:
https://digital-hacks.de/vpn-verbindung-einrichten/

You can see the code in the head section or here.

```
<script>
    var sidebar = $('#sidebar-content'),
        nav = $('.sidebar-content'),
        startPosition = sidebar .offset().top,
        stopPosition = $('#abspann').offset().top - nav.outerHeight();

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        //stick nav to top of page 
        var y = $(this).scrollTop()

        if (y > startPosition) {
            nav.addClass('sticky');
            if (y > stopPosition) {
                nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
            } else {
                nav.css('top', 0);
            }
        } else {
            nav.removeClass('sticky');
        } 
    });
</script>
```

I want that the sidebar gets attached to the screen if the user scrolls down and it should end if the ending of the sidebar has reached the element `#abspann`.

But I get a error in my code:
`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at (index):415`

How can I get this working?

I found the sourcecode [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykto7uu9/1/).

Greetings

Comment: jquery not loaded it seems

Comment: Honestly, just use http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ lib ;)

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Stick kit doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Cant add comment so posting as a answer. Try replacing $ with jQuery in your above code. Hopefully it will resolve the error.

Comment: Code is above !

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
<script>
    var nav = $('.sidebar-content'),
        startPosition = nav.offset().top,
        stopPosition = $('#abspann').offset().top - $(window).height();

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        //stick nav to top of page 
        var y = $(this).scrollTop()

        if (y > startPosition) {
            nav.addClass('sticky');
            if (y > stopPosition) {
                nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
            } else {
                nav.css('top', 0);
            }
        } else {
            nav.removeClass('sticky');
        } 
    });
</script>
```

Style `sticky` class as you desire `position: fixed` and other tweaks you need to do. it's woking on your website. I tried using the console.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to replace $ with jQuery and then try this,

```
var sidebar = jQuery('#sidebar-wrap'),
    nav = jQuery('.sidebar-content'),
    startPosition = sidebar.offset().top,
    stopPosition = jQuery('#abspann').offset().top - nav.outerHeight();

jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
    //stick nav to top of page
    var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop()

    if (y > startPosition) {
        nav.addClass('sticky');
        if (y > stopPosition) {
            nav.css('top', stopPosition - y);
        } else {
            nav.css('top', 0);
        }
    } else {
        nav.removeClass('sticky');
    } 
});
```

Also you have to add id here

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper" id="sidebar-wrap">
```

in wrapper of sidebar
and add style for sticky

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Check the site again... I still get "(index):407 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Comment: @user7422244 are you kidding me, you have put - `#sidebar-wrap` and `.sidebar-content` to the same div. please use `#sidebar-wrap` on '.wpb_wrapper' and follow the instruction from this answer, or try my answer it's working on your site.

Comment: I have moved the `#sidebar-wrap` two divs higher because this is the only place where I can put it with WordPress. But it is still not working. The reason is, in my eyes, that I get the following error: `(index):407 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Comment: @user7422244 `(index):407 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` -this error occurs when the jQuery can't find the object which has `.offset().top` are you sure that is in your page.?

Comment: I tried your code inside your web page its working fine, so it has this issue when it loads the dome,  can you try - `jQuery('#sidebar-wrap').offset().top` it may work.

Comment: I checked this by adding this code in console..it should work try again..
you have to just add id="sidebar-wrap" with the div class="wpb_wrapper".